# Python how to build dictionary from nested protobuf definitions

Tags: python, dictionary, protocol-buffers, grpc-python

This is my first time working with grpc/protobuf tech. So far, so good I have coded grpc methods for simple (flat?) protobuf definitions. However I have run into nested protobuf declarations and have no idea how to formulate the dictionary payload. Unfortunately the team the created these files is offering little to no coding support.

**Snippet of proto file:**

```
message UpdateClusterRequest {
    myapp.infrastructure.common.Context context = 1;
    myapp.infrastructure.common.MyAppEnvironment myapp_environment = 2;
    string service_name = 3;

    ClusterTemplate spec = 4;
    string config_revision = 5;

}

message ClusterTemplate {
    message MyAppSettings {
        string version = 1;
        repeated InstanceType instance_layout = 2;
        repeated ClientIDTemplate client_ids = 3;

        bool dedicated_mock_service = 4;
        int64 mock_service_replicas = 5;
    }

    message DbSettings {
        string version = 1;
        repeated DBHostTemplate db_hosts = 2;
        bool analytics_enabled = 3;
    }
```

My code snippet is below. The issue I have is I don't know how to code the ***message Cluster Template*** part into the ***playload_cluster_detail*** payload:

```
def update_cluster(client_stub, console_project_id, metadata_okta_token_and_env):

    try:

        payload_cluster_detail = {"context": {"project_id": console_project_id},
                                  "myapp_environment": common_pb2.MYAPP_ENVIRONMENT_TEST,
                                  "service_name": "web-2024-app",
                                  "config_revision": "1824866",
                                  "spec": {
                                    "MyAppSettings": {
                                        "version": "1824866-unix64-clang-debug",
                                        "branch": "web_mainline",
                                    }
                                  }
                                  }
        request = myapp_pb2.UpdateClusterRequest(**payload_cluster_detail)
        response = client_stub.get_grpc_myapp_stub(grpc_stub_method).UpdateCluster(request=request, metadata=metadata_okta_token_and_env)
```

When I run my code I get the following error:

> ValueError: Protocol message ClusterTemplate has no "MyAppSettings" field.

Comment: `MyAppSettings` is a message (type). It defines a sub-message (type) for `ClusterTemplate` but the proto is missing a field within `ClusterTemplate` that references `MyAppSettings` (type). Something like `MyAppSettings my_app_settings = 99;`

Comment: If you were to have a definition per above, the dict key would be `"my_app_settings": { "version": "blah" }` but note that `MyAppSettings` has no `branch` field so this is invalid.

Comment: thanks @DazWilkin I get how to do that based on 1 level nesting as you pasted, however, focusing specifically on 'version' How can I write that as a dictionary? And sorry please ignore the branch I deleted some lines to make this post a lot smaller.

Comment: I'll add an answer with what I used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I munged your proto file to get it to work for me (as I don't have all your dependencies):

`x.proto`:

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

// (ADDED:dazwilkin) to compile
message Context {
    string project_id = 1;
}

message UpdateClusterRequest {
    Context context = 1;
    // myapp.infrastructure.common.MyAppEnvironment myapp_environment = 2;
    string service_name = 3;

    ClusterTemplate spec = 4;
    string config_revision = 5;

}

message ClusterTemplate {
    message MyAppSettings {
        string version = 1;
        // repeated InstanceType instance_layout = 2;
        // repeated ClientIDTemplate client_ids = 3;

        bool dedicated_mock_service = 4;
        int64 mock_service_replicas = 5;
    }

    message DbSettings {
        string version = 1;
        // repeated DBHostTemplate db_hosts = 2;
        bool analytics_enabled = 3;
    }

    MyAppSettings my_app_settings = 1;
    DbSettings db_settings = 2;
}
```

**NOTE** I added `MyAppSettings my_app_settings = 1;`

Then:

```bash
python \
-m grpc_tools.protoc \
--proto_path=${PWD} \
--python_out=${PWD} \
${PWD}/x.proto
```

Then I can:

```py
import x_pb2


console_project_id = "x"

payload_cluster_detail = {
    "context": {
        "project_id": console_project_id
        },
    "service_name": "web-2024-app",
    "config_revision": "1824866",
    "spec": {
        "my_app_settings": {
            "version": "1824866-unix64-clang-debug",
        },
        "db_settings": {
            "version": "",
            "analytics_enabled": True,
        }

    }
}

x = x_pb2.UpdateClusterRequest(**payload_cluster_detail)
print(x)
```

Comment: Thank you! I was about to reply with another "but how?". After staring back and forth I was, I discovered a line identical to what you added. I failed to notice this as our message definition is fairly long and I missed it. Anywho thank you!!

Comment: It's one reason why I prefer flat (rather than nested) messages.